# Istio(0.7.1) : Circuit Breaker Doesn't work for httpConsecutiveErrors

Tags: kubernetes, devops, istio, circuit-breaker, envoyproxy

Circuit breaker doesn't trip on httpConsecutiveErrors: 1 (for 500 response). All requests pass through and give a 500 instead .
Circuit breaker should trip and should return 503(Service Unavailable) instead .

Follow the steps [Circuit breaker setup](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking.html)
.

Once httpbin is up you can simulate 500 with it
Request :

```
kubectl exec -it $FORTIO_POD -c fortio /usr/local/bin/fortio -- load -c 1 -qps 0 -n 20 -loglevel Warning http://httpbin:8000/status/500
```

Running this will simulate 20 requests returning 500 .

But if you have applied the circuit breaker if should allow just the one request as 500 and remaining requests should be tripped and a 503 should be returned . This doesn't happen.
Issue raised on github [Github issue](https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/363)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, currently Circuit Breaker is not working in the case of HTTP-500, it only works with (Http-502/3/4) till now. But for making Http-500 is in the scope of the circuit breaker the work has been started. You can check this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/istio/api/issues/909) for more detail.